# Remote debugger hits breakpoint but Visual Studio doesn't notice

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, embedded-linux, remote-debugging

Visual Studio 2019 attaches successfully to a remote trivial .NET Core 2.2 console app running on linux via ssh. If breakpoints are set in VS, the app will freeze at the appropriate spot but Visual Studio does not react. How should I try to resolve this?

I have tried compiling for core 2.0/2.1/2.2 and running the app and attaching the debugger via ssh from a combination of different users, including root, with the exact same behavior. Running an instance locally on the windows dev machine works.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for debugger to attach");
  while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Debugger attached");
  Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
}
```

I expected Visual Studio to give me a tracing arrow and show a callstack as it does when hitting the same breakpoint running locally.

Comment: When you set your breakpoint and the app "freezes" is the little circle of the breakpoint solid or hollow?

Comment: The breakpoint bullet point is solid red, no issues reported, and the debugger on the target machine must be getting the data on attaching it, as it is freezing when it is active but not when it is disabled/removed. The yellow arrow never appears however.